# Can not access Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu on another drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 but am no longer able to access Windows when rebooting. On start up my computer, which is booting through UEFI, goes straight to GRUB but there is no option to select the Windows OS. There also does not seem to be an option for Windows when selecting from the boot menu. The Windows files are still viewable in the partition I created before installing Ubuntu and Boot-Repair did not fix the problem.https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9TFcF7SKZK/ is the paste that boot repair provided me please help me i'm in trouble without windows.

These are `sudo fdisk -l` results

```
root@karl:~# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 54.97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop1: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop2: 240.82 MiB, 252493824 bytes, 493152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
Disk /dev/loop3: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop4: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
Disk /dev/loop5: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop6: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
Disk /dev/loop7: 27.9 MiB, 28405760 bytes, 55480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000AAKX-6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FB3C3F69-0430-4285-8FE3-364A118CD32E

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT3500SC        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x612b88ea

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1       206848 204799999 204593152 97.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    

Disk /dev/loop8: 29.9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
Disk /dev/loop9: 290.45 MiB, 304545792 bytes, 594816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/loop10: 4.93 GiB, 5268953088 bytes, 10290924 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdc: 14.47 GiB, 15525216256 bytes, 30322688 sectors
Disk model: v236w           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x229ce8de

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 30322687 30320640 14.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: *The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: You need to alter the grub.conf and then update grub and everything will work ur not in trouble trust me.

Comment: Run `sudo fdisk -l`, edit your question with the results.

Comment: What happens when you change your bios settings to boot from the disk that has the windows installation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit your grub.conf your not in trouble trust me, save and

```
sudo update grub
```

Comment: i have updated it but still not showing windows so i changed the internal harddisk format to gpt and thats the big mistake the contents of the hard drive are shown unknown in disks, and i cant acces any more the data of this disk can you help me.

Comment: You changed the hdd format in grub.conf? Or you have reformatted the drive to GPT? If you have done either one of these I no nothing of how to re access my stuff other then a live stick usb to access my files if you haven’t encrypted them you will get them back but if you have altered the way 1s and 0s are wrote to the disk the chances are its gone for good man, try using the cloud to back up google give you 15gb free so just make 10 accounts 150gb free, hope you find a solution

Comment: hey bro @curiouskangaroo i recovered my partition by testdisk so now tell me what can i do next to get back my windows in grub

Comment: Ok so what you wanna do is enter in root mode your grub.conf file with nano or what ever your using and sudo update grub       Then.          Sudo reboot